# Nothing happens when button is clicked in MS Access

Tags: ms-access, vba

I am working on my MS Access project, and suddenly all the buttons (on Click event) stopped working on all forms (about 11 forms)

I tried following, but no success.

1. Commented the code I was working on when this happened.
2. Deleted the code
3. Added new button with just a msg box in it.
4. Created a new form and added a  new button (Nothing happens)

I have been working on MS Access for a year now, bit never faced any issue like this.

Any help in any form is appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: when you look at the `properties>events` pane do you see the "event procedure" on the on_click event?

Comment: @LiamH, Yes it's there

Comment: Have you clicked the 'Enable This Content' security alert when the database opens?  Or the Trust Center settings have somehow been set too high?

Comment: @DarrenBartrup-Cook, I am using the same file. Hence no point in 'Enable This Content' security alert

Comment: Not sure what you mean by 'I am using the same file'.  I have a database that only contains local tables (I haven't split it yet) a few simple queries and a bit of VBA code.  It still gives a security warning when I first open it asking me to enable content - if I don't none of the buttons work.  If I up my security settings it just disables everything without asking - and it's all 'using the same file'.

Comment: Perhaps your UAC settings have changed / updated to higher setting?

Comment: Do you get a message when you manually compile your VBA project?

Comment: @random_answer_guy Tried the file on another PC, still the problem persists.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to @Bas Verlaat Tried manually compiling the code, and volla!!!! found that there was one sub which was copied erroneously twice in a form, and hence all the loss of functionality.

Thanks for help everyone. Stack Overflow is the best :)

> Lessons learned : If there is some problem in one form, the entire project can suffer.

Comment: To compile the code, go in your VBA and, in the menu, `Debug` > `Compile [Project name here]`.